# Data Binding ListBox in a User Control in the Silverlight Page

Tags: silverlight-4.0, user-controls

I have a user control that has a ListBox with a bunch of other controls.
I need to be able to bind the ListBox control in the Silverlight Page.
I need to be able to do this, so that i can use my usercontrol on several different pages and bind it to different table on each page.

Any ideas of how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can expose a DP of type IEnumerable in your UserControl and, as you feel the property change, set your ListBox's ItemsSource to that property.

Comment: I used the dependency property and the listbox itemsource is now set correctly. But when i used a dependecny property for the ListBox.SelectedItem property and tried to retrive the user selected value in the user control code behind it gives me null. How can i resolve this?

Comment: How and where are you trying to retrieve the ListBox.SelectedItem?